# Why does the following code not work with queue.SimpleQueue, but works with multiprocessing.SimpleQueue?

Tags: python, queue

The following code is taken from the book "Fluent in Python". The comments were put there by me, from different sources.

```
import sys
from time import perf_counter
from typing import NamedTuple
from multiprocessing import Process, SimpleQueue, cpu_count
from multiprocessing import queues
from primes import is_prime, NUMBERS


class PrimeResult(NamedTuple):
    n: int
    prime: bool
    elapsed: float


JobQueue = queues.SimpleQueue[int]
ResultQueue = queues.SimpleQueue[PrimeResult]


def check(n: int) -> PrimeResult:
    t0 = perf_counter()
    res = is_prime(n)
    return PrimeResult(n, res, perf_counter() - t0)


def worker(jobs: JobQueue, results: ResultQueue) -> None:
    # SimpleQueue.get(block=True, timeout=None)
    #   Remove and return an item from the queue. If optional args block is true 
    #   and timeout is None (the default), block if necessary until an item is 
    #   available. If timeout is a positive number, it blocks at most timeout 
    #   seconds and raises the Empty exception if no item was available within 
    #   that time. Otherwise (block is false), return an item if one is immediately
    #   available, else raise the Empty exception (timeout is ignored in that case).
    while n := jobs.get():
        print(n)
        results.put(check(n))
    # the following line, will tell main to increase procs_done by 1.
    results.put(PrimeResult(0, False, 0.0))


def start_jobs(procs: int, jobs: JobQueue, results: ResultQueue) -> None:
    for n in NUMBERS:
        jobs.put(n)
    for _ in range(procs):
        proc = Process(target=worker, args=(jobs, results))
        proc.start()
        # zero will evaluate to False in the While loop of worker function
        jobs.put(0)
        


def report(procs: int, results: ResultQueue) -> int:
    checked = 0
    procs_done = 0
    while procs_done < procs:
        n, prime, elapsed = results.get()
        if n == 0:
            procs_done += 1
        else:
            checked += 1
            label = "P" if prime else " "
            print(f"{n:16} {label} {elapsed:9.6f}s")
    return checked


def main() -> None:   
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        procs = cpu_count()
    else:
        procs = int(sys.argv[1])
    print(f"Checking {len(NUMBERS)} numbers with {procs} processes:")
    t0 = perf_counter()
    jobs: JobQueue = SimpleQueue()
    results: ResultQueue = SimpleQueue()
    start_jobs(procs, jobs, results)
    checked = report(procs, results)
    elapsed = perf_counter() - t0
    print(f"{checked} checks in {elapsed:.2f}s")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If I now change the import to `from queue import SimpleQueue`, this same code does not work, even though in the python documentation

> The [multiprocessing.]Queue, SimpleQueue and JoinableQueue types are
> multi-producer, multi-consumer FIFO queues modelled on the queue.Queue
> class in the standard library. They differ in that Queue lacks the
> task_done() and join() methods introduced into Python 2.5’s
> queue.Queue class.

The problem seems to be that the processes will never get the zero valued tasked, and I'm not sure why... This will never allows to exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

After much debugging, I figured out that somehow the queues were not being shared... The results queue seemed to be restarted, and the jobs also, but with increasing number of zeros...
Then it dawned on me that I should be using something intended for threads which will by definition share the same memory... and it's that!

The queue module seems to be used for threads, whereas, if we want specifically queues for processes, we should use necessarily  the multiprocessing module.

Below is the code that worked for me:

```
import sys
from time import perf_counter
from typing import NamedTuple
from multiprocessing import cpu_count, #Process,SimpleQueue
from threading import Thread

# below is for multithreading
from queue import (
    Queue as SimpleQueue,
    Empty,
    Full
)

# The Queue, SimpleQueue and JoinableQueue types are multi-producer, multi-consumer 
# FIFO queues modelled on the queue.Queue class in the standard library. 
# They differ in that Queue lacks the task_done() and join() methods introduced into 
# Python 2.5’s queue.Queue class.

# from multiprocessing import queues
from primes import is_prime, NUMBERS


class PrimeResult(NamedTuple):
    n: int
    prime: bool
    elapsed: float


JobQueue = SimpleQueue[int]
ResultQueue = SimpleQueue[PrimeResult]


def check(n: int) -> PrimeResult:
    t0 = perf_counter()
    res = is_prime(n)
    print(f"inside check with {n}")
    return PrimeResult(n, res, perf_counter() - t0)


def worker(jobs: JobQueue, results: ResultQueue) -> None:
    # SimpleQueue.get(block=True, timeout=None)
    #   Remove and return an item from the queue. If optional args block is true
    #   and timeout is None (the default), block if necessary until an item is
    #   available. If timeout is a positive number, it blocks at most timeout
    #   seconds and raises the Empty exception if no item was available within
    #   that time. Otherwise (block is false), return an item if one is immediately
    #   available, else raise the Empty exception (timeout is ignored in that case).
    try:
        n = jobs.get()
        while n!=0: 
            print(f"\nGetting element {n} in jobs queue")
        # Queue.put(item, block=True, timeout=None)
        # Put item into the queue. If optional args block is true and timeout is
        # None (the default), block if necessary until a free slot is available.
        # If timeout is a positive number, it blocks at most timeout seconds and
        # raises the Full exception if no free slot was available within that time.
        # Otherwise (block is false), put an item on the queue if a free slot is
        # immediately available, else raise the Full exception (timeout is ignored in
        # that case).
            results.put(check(n))
            jobs.task_done()
            print(f"exited check with {n}")
            n = jobs.get()
            print(f"exited get with new {n}")
            
    except Empty or Full as e:
        print(f"exception :{repr(e)}")
    # the following line, will tell main to increase procs_done by 1.
    print(f"exited while with n = {n}")
    
    results.put(PrimeResult(0, False, 0.0))
    print(f"after results.put(PrimeResult(0, False, 0.0))")


def start_jobs(procs: int, jobs: JobQueue, results: ResultQueue) -> None:
    for n in NUMBERS:
        # we're putting all the numbers on the queue.
        jobs.put(n)
        print(f"putting element {n} in jobs queue")
    for _ in range(procs):
        # proc = Process(target=worker, args=(jobs, results))
        # proc.start()
        # start()
        # Start the process’s activity.
        # This must be called at most once per process object. It arranges for the
        # object’s run() method to be invoked in a separate process.

        # run()
        # Method representing the process’s activity.
        # You may override this method in a subclass.
        # The standard run() method invokes the callable object passed to the
        # object’s constructor as the target argument, if any, with sequential and
        # keyword arguments taken from the args and kwargs arguments, respectively.
        thrd = Thread(target=worker, args=(jobs, results))
        thrd.start()

        # zero will evaluate to False in the While loop of worker function
        # The jobs queue already has all the numbers. Now, we're putting the poison
        # pill to make the worker function finish, thus killing that corresponding
        # process.
        jobs.put(0)
        print(f"putting element {0} in jobs queue")


def report(procs: int, results: ResultQueue) -> int:
    checked = 0
    procs_done = 0
    while procs_done < procs:
        n, prime, elapsed = results.get()
        if n == 0:
            procs_done += 1
        else:
            checked += 1
            label = "P" if prime else " "
            print(f"{n:16} {label} {elapsed:9.6f}s")
        print(f"\tprocs_done = {procs_done}")
    return checked


def main() -> None:
    # sys.argv - The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script.
    # argv[0] is the script name (it is operating system dependent whether this
    # is a full pathname or not). If the command was executed using the -c
    # command line option to the interpreter, argv[0] is set to the string '-c'.
    # If no script name was passed to the Python interpreter, argv[0] is the empty
    # string. To loop over the standard input, or the list of files given on the
    # command line, see the fileinput module.

    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        procs = cpu_count()
    else:
        procs = int(sys.argv[1])
    print(f"Checking {len(NUMBERS)} numbers with {procs} processes:")
    t0 = perf_counter()
    jobs: JobQueue = SimpleQueue()
    results: ResultQueue = SimpleQueue()
    start_jobs(procs, jobs, results)
    checked = report(procs, results)
    elapsed = perf_counter() - t0
    print(f"{checked} checks in {elapsed:.2f}s")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```